# Sending a message to a datastream from the NEST client says missing timestamp

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, elasticsearch, nest

I am trying to send message via the CreateAsync function from the NEST API and I get a missing timestamp error

The code I'm using is

```
var node = new Uri($"{_baseUrl}:{_elasticPort}");
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(node);
settings.BasicAuthentication("user", "pass");
var elasticClient = new ElasticClient(settings);
var elasticResponse = await elasticClient.IndexAsync<Message>(new(_message, DateTime.UtcNow), d =>
{
    d.OpType(OpType.Create);
    d.Index(_index);
    d.Id("id");
    return d;
});
Console.WriteLine(elasticResponse);
```

And the error I'm getting is

```
Invalid NEST response built from a unsuccessful (400) low level call on PUT: /index-2022.07.24/_doc/id?op_type=create
{
  "Error": {
    "Headers": {},
    "RootCause": [
      {
        "AdditionalProperties": {},
        "BytesLimit": null,
        "BytesWanted": null,
        "CausedBy": null,
        "Column": null,
        "FailedShards": [],
        "Grouped": null,
        "Index": null,
        "IndexUUID": null,
        "Language": null,
        "LicensedExpiredFeature": null,
        "Line": null,
        "Phase": null,
        "Reason": "failed to parse",
        "ResourceId": [],
        "ResourceType": null,
        "Script": null,
        "ScriptStack": [],
        "Shard": null,
        "StackTrace": null,
        "Type": "mapper_parsing_exception"
      }
    ],
    "AdditionalProperties": {},
    "BytesLimit": null,
    "BytesWanted": null,
    "CausedBy": {
      "AdditionalProperties": {},
      "BytesLimit": null,
      "BytesWanted": null,
      "CausedBy": null,
      "Column": null,
      "FailedShards": [],
      "Grouped": null,
      "Index": null,
      "IndexUUID": null,
      "Language": null,
      "LicensedExpiredFeature": null,
      "Line": null,
      "Phase": null,
      "Reason": "data stream timestamp field [@timestamp] is missing",
      "ResourceId": [],
      "ResourceType": null,
      "Script": null,
      "ScriptStack": [],
      "Shard": null,
      "StackTrace": null,
      "Type": "illegal_argument_exception"
    },
    "Column": null,
    "FailedShards": [],
    "Grouped": null,
    "Index": null,
    "IndexUUID": null,
    "Language": null,
    "LicensedExpiredFeature": null,
    "Line": null,
    "Phase": null,
    "Reason": "failed to parse",
    "ResourceId": [],
    "ResourceType": null,
    "Script": null,
    "ScriptStack": [],
    "Shard": null,
    "StackTrace": null,
    "Type": "mapper_parsing_exception"
  },
  "Status": 400
}
{
  "Message": "Request failed to execute. Call: Status code 400 from: PUT /index-2022.07.24/_doc/id?op_type=create. ServerError: Type: mapper_parsing_exception Reason: \u0022failed to parse\u0022 CausedBy: \u0022Type: illegal_argument_exception Reason: \u0022data stream timestamp field [@timestamp] is missing\u0022\u0022",
  "Data": {},
  "InnerException": null,
  "HelpLink": null,
  "Source": null,
  "HResult": -2146233088,
  "StackTrace": null
}
```

I tried finding a detailed description of this API or look up a similiar problem, but it seems like the datastreams concept is fairly new and all the related posts are too old.

Edit - I realized I forgot to add the record I'm using to make the message, so:

```
record Message(string Message, DateTime @timestamp);
```

EDIT: I evaluated the request with wireshark, it has a timestamp but the item is formatted as timestamp not @timestamp, I can't seem to find an api that allows me to format the name of the item correctly as it is named @timestamp on the record...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason the serializer took out the @ at the beginning of the type name...
Adding this line to the settings solved it.

```
settings.DefaultMappingFor<Message>(m => m.PropertyName(p => p.timestamp, "@timestamp"));
```